# Getting an error when running ANT command on build.xml

Tags: eclipse, selenium, ant, testng, build.xml

Testng by itself works and I can get results generating.  I'm trying to use XSLT reports to make things prettier but I'm not having any luck.  Here is how eclipse is setup:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgiNP.jpg

**BUILD.XML FILE:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE project [
]>

<project name="TestNG" default="usage" basedir=".">  

<!-- ========== Initialize Properties =================================== -->
<property environment="env"/>
<property name="ws.home" value="${basedir}"/>
<property name="ws.jars" value="E:\Selenium Main\TestNG\lib"/>
<property name="test.dest" value="${ws.home}/build"/>
<property name="test.src" value="${ws.home}/src"/>
      <property name="ng.result" value="test-output"/>

<!--target name="start-selenium-server">
    <java jar="${ws.home}/lib/selenium-server.jar"/>
</target-->

<target name="setClassPath" unless="test.classpath">
    <path id="classpath_jars">
        <fileset dir="${ws.jars}" includes="*.jar"/>
    </path>
    <pathconvert pathsep=":" 
        property="test.classpath" 
        refid="classpath_jars"/>
</target>

<target name="init" depends="setClassPath">
    <tstamp>
        <format property="start.time" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm aa" />
    </tstamp>
    <condition property="ANT" 
        value="${env.ANT_HOME}/bin/ant.bat" 
        else="${env.ANT_HOME}/bin/ant">
        <os family="windows" />
    </condition>
    <taskdef name="testng" classpath="${test.classpath}"
           classname="org.testng.TestNGAntTask" />

</target>

<!-- all -->
<target name="all">
</target>

<!-- clean -->
<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${test.dest}"/>
</target>

<!-- compile -->
<target name="compile" depends="init, clean" > 
               <delete includeemptydirs="true" quiet="true">
        <fileset dir="${test.dest}" includes="**/*"/>
               </delete>
    <echo message="making directory..."/>
               <mkdir dir="${test.dest}"/>
    <echo message="classpath------: ${test.classpath}"/>
    <echo message="compiling..."/>
    <javac 
        debug="true" 
        destdir="${test.dest}" 
        srcdir="${test.src}" 
        target="1.5" 
        classpath="${test.classpath}"
    >
    </javac>
  </target>

<!-- build -->
<target name="build" depends="init">
</target>

<!-- run -->
<target name="run" depends="compile">
<testng classpath="${test.classpath}:${test.dest}" suitename="sivaprasad"> 
        <xmlfileset dir="${ws.home}" includes="testng.xml"/>
    </testng>
    <!--
    <testng classpath="${test.classpath}:${test.dest}" groups="fast">
        <classfileset dir="${test.dest}" includes="example1/*.class"/>
    </testng>
    -->
</target>

<target name="usage">
    <echo>
        ant run will execute the test
    </echo>
</target>

      <path id="test.c">
              <fileset dir="${ws.jars}" includes="*.jar"/>
      </path>

        <target name="makexsltreports">
              <mkdir dir="${ws.home}/XSLT_Reports/output"/>

   <xslt in="${ng.result}/testng-results.xml" style="src/xslt/testng-results.xsl"
                   out="${ws.home}/XSLT_Reports/output/index.html"                  classpathref="test.c" processor="SaxonLiaison">
                  <param name="testNgXslt.outputDir"  expression="${ws.home}/XSLT_Reports/output/"/>
   <param name="testNgXslt.showRuntimeTotals" expression="true"/>
              </xslt>
          </target>

<!-- ****************** targets not used ****************** -->
</project>
```

**ERROR MESSAGE:**
E:\Selenium Main\TestNG>ant makexsltreports
Buildfile: E:\Selenium Main\TestNG\build.xml

makexsltreports:
     [xslt] Processing E:\Selenium Main\TestNG\test-output\testng-results.xml to E:\Selenium Main\TestNG\XSLT_Reports\output\index.html
     [xslt] Loading stylesheet E:\Selenium Main\TestNG\src\xslt\testng-results.xsl
     [xslt] E:\Selenium Main\TestNG\src\xslt\testng-results.xsl:34:71: Fatal Error! Error reported by XML parser Cause: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/E:/Selenium%20Main/TestNG/src/xslt/testng-results.xsl; lineNumber: 34; columnNumber
: 71; Attribute name "data-pjax-transient" associated with an element type "meta" must be followed by the ' = ' character.
     [xslt] : Fatal Error! org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/E:/Selenium%20Main/TestNG/src/xslt/testng-results.xsl; lineNumber: 34; columnNumber: 71; Attribute name "data-pjax-transient" associated with an element type "meta" must be fol
lowed by the ' = ' character. Cause: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/E:/Selenium%20Main/TestNG/src/xslt/testng-results.xsl; lineNumber: 34; columnNumber: 71; Attribute name "data-pjax-transient" associated with an element type "meta" m
ust be followed by the ' = ' character.
     [xslt] Failed to process E:\Selenium Main\TestNG\test-output\testng-results.xml

BUILD FAILED
E:\Selenium Main\TestNG\build.xml:100: Fatal error during transformation using E:\Selenium Main\TestNG\src\xslt\testng-results.xsl: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/E:/Selenium%20Main/TestNG/src/xslt/testng-results.xsl; lineNumber: 34;
columnNumber: 71; Attribute name "data-pjax-transient" associated with an element type "meta" must be followed by the ' = ' character.

Total time: 1 second

E:\Selenium Main\TestNG>

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I fixed the issue. testng-results.xsl was the problem it looks like. I replaced the file with another copy found on the internet and it works now!